# keycloak external command line client examples

Tags: keycloak

Are there any good examples out there to authenticate a command line client with keycloak?

When I search for "keycloak command line client examples" I am getting results that show how to use the existing admin command line client.

I want to create a command line client for my users to authenticate with my app.

Comment: What did you mean with "a command line client for my users"?

Comment: Rather than command link then use keycloak rest api which can be access through rest client.